# Step to add new column in production server (SQL Server 2008)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using a SQL Server 2008 database.

My project is live. Now I want to add a new column in my `employee` table.

How can I do that?

Please tell me the idea

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole lot to consider there.  Just off the top of my head:

- Verify anything that accesses that table will not be negatively impacted.  If anything is using `SELECT *` it is likely to blow up.  Similarly, anything that selects from, or inserts into the DB by column index will need to be changed
- Changing a column can require a drop/recreate of the table- make sure that no one will be accessing the table when you're making the change.  This includes scheduled jobs, triggers, etc.
- Make sure your back-ups are up to date.  If something goes wrong, you want to be able to get back to where you were.

All in all, I'd say your best bet- if the option is available- is to follow these steps in a Development, and then in a QA environment to make sure you are as certain as possible about anything that will be impacted by the change so you can make the necessary adjustments.

Once you're sure about what you're doing, [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) is the command you want, and Microsoft has [plenty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189614.aspx) of documentation about how to use it.  Alternatively, the SQL Server Management Studio gives a GUI for making the changes as well.

Comment: my db is in live i dont know whom using the table. on the time what i want to add new column.... please tell me u'r idea?

Comment: If you have to modify a table and you don't know what depends on said table... STOP.  You have a major problem beyond whatever you're fixing by adding a column.  Dig through your system documentation and find every reference to your table that you can.  Failing that (maybe even with that) make sure your manager/Lead/whatever knows that this is a potential breaking change to an unknown number of other systems- and to be expecting an inundation of bugs because of it.

Answer (score 2):

When adding a column to a table with data, the column should be NULL or you need a default value

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD AnotherColumn int NULL
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD AnotherColumn int NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT DF_myTable _AnotherColumn  DEFAULT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [alter table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

```
alter table YourTable add NewColumn int
```